# Are questions about videography on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, off-topic

According to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic?newreg=fc67f968d3f94b0c9abee0ee804cbdf8), it seems that the answer is yes, though not explicit. However, when browsing the front page I have a feeling that this site is more about technical issues. I think videography questions, on the other hand, are like a [Writing SE](http://writing.stackexchange.com/) question in video format.

Is that on-topic? Below is my example question.

---

I have a vlog to convey my thoughts in an important topic, in a form of a travel vlog, so that the video can be both contemplating, relaxing and exciting at the same time. It's like parallel narrative. I have the hook to begin the vlog, but I don't know how the transition after the hook should be before going back to the main topic.

I think the transition should:

- explain that I'm on a travel (the hook doesn't explicitly explain that)
- create positive mood (by showing interesting moments during the travel)
- be short enough (to not distract the main topic)?

In my vision, the format is similar to [this vlog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EthqIhPtd2I). But for this vlog, the audience already expects that this is a travel vlog, so its transition only needs to show interesting things, and thus can be kept short (16 seconds). But my vlog is more complex, and I wonder how to keep the attentional span. I can still simply say "I'll discuss this in my travel" straightforwardly, but perhaps it will spoil the hook?

The transition doesn't need to show any logo (I don't need any brand).

Also, do you know which kind of music that suits the transition? I have visited Artlist and Epidemic but I still don't know how what music genre and mood that is contemplating, relaxing and exciting at the same time.

<sup>Related: [Are questions about organizing video scripts and post-production on-topic?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2067/11428) on Writing</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the concept behind the question related to video production/editing would be on topic, but it would need to be cleaned up in to a question that fits the format of the site better.  Perhaps putting together a sample and then explaining what you think doesn't work about it and asking about techniques to fix the problem might work and would narrow it a bit from just completely open ended questions on spitballing ideas.

The music portion has similar fit the format concerns, but if you can address those, it would likely fit well on the Sound Design SE.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that your core question is opinion based and broad. There may be answers, but they may all be different, and Stack Exchange is a very bad medium for lists of answers.

Your music question is entirely off topic - it's opinion based. What would suit you may be entirely wrong for someone else.

Comment: What is the difference between lists of answers and having different perspectives (which SE encourages that)